# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error initiating Brave browser using Selenium on MAC

Tags: java, selenium, ssl, selenium-webdriver, brave

I am trying to launch and control Brave browser using Selenium. It is part of a larger project where other popular browsers are automated as well. I used ChromeOptions and gave the path location of the Brave binary.

Code trials:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/user/Downloads/chrome/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The browser gets launched. But says,

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
www.abcxyzabcxyzabc.univer.se uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

And Eclipse console says:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.119)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
```

I have not implemented TestNG or Maven or anything.

The website itself is built using OnUniverse.com Website builder.

- Selenium version: '3.141.59'
- Brave browser version: 'Version 1.47.186
- Chromium: 109.0.5414.119 (Official Build) (x86_64)

System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.5', java.version: '17.0.1'`

Driver info:

```
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 109.0.5414.119, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604da..., userDataDir: /var/folders/sg/x5dk1wqd2g7...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52634}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

### [ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH](https://www.plesk.com/blog/various/how-to-fix-err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch/)

Browsers always checks the SSL certificate of the website every time you try to connect to it. The process to ensure that the site is legitimate and the site has the right protocol put in place to ensure that the user's connection is secure, is known as a TLS handshake. TLS (Transport Layer Security) is a protocol that ensures secure communication between a user computer and a webserver.

Incase the user's browser and the webserver fail to support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite during the TLS handshake in those cases the browser can display the error message *`ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`*.

---

### This usecase

In your case it's possibly the mismatch between either of the following configuration:

- Java *v17.0.1*
- Selenium *v3.141.59*
- ChromeDriver/Chrome *v109.0*

---

### Solution

A possible solution may be to use the compatible version as follows:

- *JDK 8u351*
- Selenium *v4.8.0*
- ChromeDriver/Chrome *v109.0*

Using the above configuration the following code block works perfect on my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) system:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://relatedwords.org/relatedto/Fishsticks");
```

Comment: Your configuration worked. Thanks. Initially, I feared Selenium 4 might not work. So I went with 3.141. But now I used Selenium 4. And it works.